# Hide Recognized Member text from the RM's flairs in the Collectives

Tags: script, design

#### About

With the launch of [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-what-are) on Stack Overflow, whenever a recognized member post an answer within their respective collective, there will be a "badge" underneath their flair which shows that they are an RM.

[image]

After some discussion, it seems that this new look is causing some distraction and disturbance in the natural "order" of the Stack Overflow's Q&A.

This script removes this badge along with the text to show the flair without it (Thanks to [@Makyen](https://stackapps.com/users/29529/makyen) for their help).

[image]

While this cannot be considered a solution for this problem (there is an [ongoing discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424338/change-remove-recognized-text-from-the-rms-flair) and a `feature-request` to remove the badge altogether), it aims to provide a workaround in the interim.

#### Installation

[Click to install with a script manager](https://github.com/MdoubleDash/Remove_RM_Flair/raw/main/Remove%20RM%20Flair.user.js). **N.B.** I have only tested this with Tampermonkey on Firefox.

#### Repository

Here is the source code for this userscript; [source code repo](https://github.com/MdoubleDash/Remove_RM_Flair)